# Engine misfire and poor mileage

Tags: chevrolet, misfire, suburban

My 2015 Chevy Suburban has 180k miles and now it gave me a check engine light code with a misfire. It shakes a little bit and does not give good fuel mileage. Also, the reader on the speedometer use to give about 200 miles on a half tank. It also makes a noise on the area where the intake is on top of the engine, where the throttle body is located. I have not changed plugs yet. Any feedback would be appreciated. I think it's a misfire 2 code.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have the exact code for the misfire? Do you mean by "misfire 2 code" that the #2 cylinder is misfiring? It could be either the coil, spark plug, or injector not working.

Comment: I would suggest you cure the misfire, give it a good service then re-evaluate the mileage....

Comment: Do you get the code P0302 repeatedly after clearing the codes?  That is, is it always the same cylinder?  I had that problem, in my case I swapped the ignition coils around, cleaned the throttle body and checked the plug gap.  It turned out that when I swapped the plugs and ignition coils to other cylinders, the misfire moved with the ignition coils, so I knew that was the problem.  In general there are a [lot of problems](https://repairpal.com/obd-ii-code-p0300) that can cause misfires.

Answer (score 0):

Shaking is usually a giveaway that a cylinder is misfiring, which would fit with the code (the exact code would be helpful). Usually I would say you need to check the plugs, wires, coils, etc, however the fact you're hearing a noise near the intake could mean you have a problem with your intake manifold, which could also cause misfiring. I would check your plugs, cables, and coils, but I would also check the intake manifolds (assuming a V engine - it is a suburban after all). Look for cracks and check for a good seal, make sure they are torqued down to spec.

You could also have a vacuum leak causing rough running, which could also account for the noise you hear. You need to track down the source of that noise. If the source of the sound isn't easy to track you can use a piece of tubing as a stethoscope.